# What multifunctional printer has good support for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, printer, colors, laser-printer

I would like to buy a **multifunctional color laser printer** (printer, scanner, copy machine). However as I am new to Mac I don't know which brand has good driver support for Mac OS X.

I have connected my current hp psc to my Mac successfully, but the drivers seem only very rudimentary - no way to control the quality of print, color/grayscale printing or check the status of cartridges.

I would like to avoid buying an expensive new printer and finding out that it's crippled on Mac in comparison to Windows.

Is there perhaps a printer brand with a history of quality MacOS drivers?

Comment: Good question - I'd like to know too

Comment: @VoY - so did you get that Epson one? Can you vouch for it too?

Comment: @Jonik - postponed buying it after christmas. I definitely plan on getting one though, so I can let you know if it is still relevant. Or you let me know pls, if you got one in the meantime :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Epson](http://www.epson.com/) printers have a long history of working very well with Mac OS.

[image]

[Epson Artisan 710](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/consumer/consDetail.jsp?BV_UseBVCookie=yes&oid=63084663) is one I have used (10.4-10.5-10.6) with great results.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. It should probably be noted that this is an ink jet printer, not laser (which is what OP asked for), even though they claim it has "laser quality".

Comment: I'm generally not against the idea of an ink printer, but I have two issues with them:

1) using a highlighter is problematic on text printed by an ink printer
2) I don't print color as much and the ink cartridges don't seem to handle well longer periods of storage.

Perhaps modern ink printers have solved this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I've been happy with my Brother MFC-7840W thus far.  It has drivers that tell me fancy things, and it had no problem hooking up to my (Airport) network.

It's not a color laser printer, just a B&W, but maybe they make color as well?

(Note, I was *not* happy with the Brother inkjets.  Drivers were OK, but ink hardly lasted at all, and it wouldn't let you print B&W if you were out of blue.)

Comment: Brother *color* laser multifunction printers: http://www.brother-usa.com/mfc/Color_Laser_Multifunction/. It seems like the cheapest of those costs about $100 more than the MFC-7840W... so not too bad, I guess.